# function chaining in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am rotating a canvas in html5.After the completion of that rotation i am implying a conditional statement but the condition is getting checked in the beginning of rotation animation ,what should i do to chain the conditional statement (if(wrong==3){......}) after the Rotate(arg2) function.
Here's my code:

```
Rotate(arg2);

if (wrong == 3) {
    WinJS.Navigation.navigate("pages/gameOver/gameOver.html");
}

function Rotate(arg) {

    rotateInterval = setInterval(function () {
        arg.save();
        arg.clearRect(-100,-100, arg.canvas.width, arg.canvas.height);


        if (flag2 == false) ang += 5;
        else ang -= 5;


        arg.rotate(ang * Math.PI / 180);

        if (ang == 180) flag2 = true;

        if (flag2 == true && ang == 0) {
            clearInterval(rotateInterval)
            flag2 = false;
        }

        arg.drawImage(bowl, -90, -90, 180, 180);
        arg.restore();

    }, 10);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

After calling setInterval(), the function Rotate() will return right away, before your interval function parameter actually executes.  You need to check your condition at the end of your rotate() function, within the setInterval() function parameter.